# MSSQL Find Weekly Records from a Start & End Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the set up:
I have a table with 
Id
employee
ContractStartDate
ContractEndDate

I am try to find all employees who work say last week, last week being 
monday(11/04/2016) and friday (15/04/2016)

What is the best query to run ?
I have a large database.

Comment: Consider posting an example of your table and the searches you have done already...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like......

### Previous Week's Start and End

```
Select * From TableName 
WHERE ContractStartDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, GETDATE()), 0)
 AND  ContractEndDate   <  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, GETDATE()), 6)
```

### This Week's Start and End

```
Select * From TableName 
WHERE ContractStartDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
 AND  ContractEndDate   <  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 5
```